# median by date excel

Tags: excel, vba

My current (simplified) data set is shown below. It has the date and a column called `x`.
I want to compute the median for each different date, but still list them line by line, like seen in my desired data set below.

I have tried to combine the `median` and `if` function to do this, however I can't get it to work line by line like my desired result below.

How can I achieve this on excel? Thanks.

**current**

[image: current]

**desired**

[image: desired]

```
date        x   median
1/01/2021   6   8
1/01/2021   8   8
1/01/2021   9   8
1/01/2021   5   8
1/01/2021   8   8
2/01/2021   4   7
2/01/2021   4   7
2/01/2021   7   7
2/01/2021   7   7
2/01/2021   9   7
3/01/2021   8   4
3/01/2021   2   4
3/01/2021   6   4
3/01/2021   5   4
3/01/2021   2   4
3/01/2021   3   4
4/01/2021   5   3.5
4/01/2021   2   3.5
5/01/2021   8   4
5/01/2021   4   4
5/01/2021   3   4
```

Comment: use the table insert tool via [edit] to insert data that people can actually copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below array formula. Array formula needs to enter by `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(B:B,MIN(IF($A$1:$A$22=A2,ROW($A$1:$A$22),""))):INDEX(B:B,MAX(IF($A$1:$A$22=A2,ROW($A$1:$A$22),""))))
```

If you have `Excel-365` then can use simplified formula like below.

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER($B$2:$B$22,$A$2:$A$22=A2))
```

[image]